# language change via localStorage

Tags: javascript, php, html, local-storage

The language on the site is changed using `<select> <option value = ""> </option>` The language change is successful.

```
<select class="tt-select" id="lang" name="forma" onchange="location = this.value;">
    <option value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(return_i18n_setlang_url('en')); ?>">ENG</option>
    <option value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(return_i18n_setlang_url('ru')); ?>">RUS</option>
    <option value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(return_i18n_setlang_url('de')); ?>">DEU</option>
    <option value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(return_i18n_setlang_url('es')); ?>">SPA</option>                             </select>
```

After choosing the language, the page is reloaded and the first value from the list is displayed. How do I make the selected language display?

They advised to use localStorage, but I don't understand anything about it. I used Google to do this, it doesn't work::

```
<script>
         (function(){
                var select = document.querySelector('#lang');
                if (localStorage.selectedIndex !== undefined) {
                    select.selectedIndex = localStorage.selectedIndex;
                }
                select.onchange = function() {
                    localStorage.selectedIndex = this.selectedIndex;
                }
            })()
</script>
```

Code `<?php echo htmlspecialchars(return_i18n_setlang_url('es')); ?>` forces the site to serve content in the desired language. I understand that it needs to be given in another way, but I don't understand how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use js at all for this purpose, PHP is aware of the language you selected, use it to print the `selected` attribute in the appropriate `<option>`:

```
// assuming the PHP variable $lang contains the selected language
<select class="tt-select" id="lang" name="forma" onchange="location = this.value;">
    <option <?php echo $lang == "en" ? "selected" : "" ?> value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(return_i18n_setlang_url('en')); ?>">ENG</option>
    <option <?php echo $lang == "ru" ? "selected" : "" ?> value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(return_i18n_setlang_url('ru')); ?>">RUS</option>
    <option <?php echo $lang == "de" ? "selected" : "" ?> value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(return_i18n_setlang_url('de')); ?>">DEU</option>
    <option <?php echo $lang == "es" ? "selected" : "" ?> value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(return_i18n_setlang_url('es')); ?>">SPA</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Doesn't work, the page refreshes and everything is reset by default. Code <? Php echo htmlspecialchars (return_i18n_setlang_url ('de')); ?> "generates a link https:// site. org/?setlang=de". I can write it with my hands and the language switch will still happen.

Comment: Ok, then php gets the language from $_GET['setlang'], use that instead of my $lang variable:
<option <?php echo $_GET['setlang'] == "en" ? "selected" : "" ?> value......

Comment: Glad to help! Can you please flag my answer as accepted (the green tick)? Thanks!

Comment: I can still disturb you, how to make sure that when you go to another page, the selected item is not installed by default (the first in the list)?

Comment: I'm not sure about what you're asking, anyway, this solution works whenever the $_GET['setlang'] is set, which is whenever the URL contains ?setlang=langcode.
I would assume that when you go to another page and a language is selected, the GET variable will still be there so that the correct language is set.

Comment: Copied your code without any corrections or additions. If it's not difficult for you, go to the site and select any language other than English. And then go to another page (works only on the desktop version) autostyling. info